# MySQL GROUP BY (if)

Tags: mysql, sql

edited: sorry badly asked..

i want to GROUP BY a variable only if another variable is equal.

i have this:

```
username       name       forename

jpumpkin_01    Pumpkin    Jack
jpumpkin_02    Pumpkin    Jack
pnice          Nice       Paul
mpumpkin       Pumpkin    Michael
```

i display the content with:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...
```

this lists all entries:

```
Pumpkin    Jack
Pumpkin    Jack
Nice       Paul
Pumpkin    Michael
```

"Pumpkin Jack" is listed double. I use GROUP BY 'name'

```
... GROUP BY name
```

Now, "Pumpkin Jack" is listed one time, but "Pumpkin Michael" is in the group too, and disapeared.

How can i list also Michael?

Thank you for answers and hints..

rgs

R

Comment: `GROUP BY name, forename` ???  If not, sample data and desired results would help explain what you really mean.

Comment: what do you mean when forename = forename?   you can group by a case expression but in the case expression you cannot compare 1 row value to another rather you have to compare the scalar values within a row to the same row, variables, etc.  GROUP BY CASE WHEN forename = 'Matt' THEN forename ELSE 'Not Matt' END would make 2 rows 1 for Matt and 1 for Not Matt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The GROUP BY is not conditional. So what you can do is something like this: "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY name, forename".